# Xcode: Dismiss keyboard after tapping autofill

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Swift, I want to detect when the user has finished adding their username/password using autofill (from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill) and not reopen the keyboard, since they're presumably done using the keyboard.

Here's how I've setup their username/password inputs:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    name.textContentType = .username
    password.textContentType = .password

    loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.loginPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func loginPressed() {
    // Making server calls here
}
```

Right now, after I hit an autofill username, my iOS runs the FaceID check, then reopens the keyboard. The user has to manually close the keyboard after.

Answer (score -1):

When a user uses autofill, depending on which type of view you use to get text input, a certain delegate method is called, as well as a `textDidChangeNotification` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow)).  For `UITextField` the method is ([`textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield)).  The string passed in is whatever new string is added, and "normally contains only the single new character that was typed" but if the user uses autofill, or pastes in a password, the number of characters in the string will be longer.  You could try checking for that and calling `endEditing` if more than one new character is added.

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     name.textContentType = .username
     password.textContentType = .password

    //set delegate
      name.delegate = self
      password.delegate = self

      loginButton.addTarget(self, action: 
                #selector(self.loginPressed), 
         for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func loginPressed() {
// Making server calls here
}
extension UIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate
{
   func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       if textField == name
       {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
         }
       }
       return true
   }
}
```

Comment: I know how to close the keyboard in general, but my question is how to do it after a FaceID password autofill

Comment: yes, edited my answer. it's worked in our app. so, you can try it.